# How to deal with non-manifold vertices for 3d printing

Tags: blender

I am working on modeling a shape for 3d printing, but I'm running into a problem with it having non-manifold vertices. I've ensured that the faces are oriented properly, but it still says these vertices are non-manifold. Anyone have ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The fact that I was trying to make the long top, outside, and bottom piece one single face was the problem. The vertices where the center section met the inside of the outer part of the design were being overlapped by the edge from the single long face. Instead, I added the vertices (points in red) in that spot, at the top, and in both places on the mirror side of the shape. After that I recreated the faces between the new vertices, checked for manifold vertices, and got none.[image: Fixed shape manifold]